# AWS IAM policy for S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket and an IAM user and I want the user to be able to perform some action on it via access key (mainly some sync from local to s3 via cli to backup some data).

Currently the bucket has all the public access blocked and has no bucket policy.

I'm trying to attach a policy to the user to perform the needed actions on a specific bucket folder (I know S3 technically does not have folders), so I wrote a custom policy and attached directly to it:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/user-folder/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/user-folder"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Testing the policy via the IAM Policy Simulator all the 4 actions are reported as allowed, but also for each there is a warning:
[image]
[image]

Trying to perform a `s3 sync` i get the error

```
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I'm not very skilled on IAM policies/permission, but updating the IAM policy resource section removing the desired directory make the sync work fine:

```json
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
```

Do I need to set up a bucket policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to change your initial IAM policy to the following:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPutGetDelete",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/user-folder/*",
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {"s3:prefix": "user-folder/*"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

See that I have put the list bucket action allow on another statement and remove the "user-folder" "path" (should be referred as key path).

Let me know if that works.

Updated: Based on comment suggestions, the following will limit it to specific key file paths.

Comment: Looks good. To further limit the `ListBucket` capability to a specific folder, see: [Amazon S3: Allows IAM users access to their S3 home directory, programmatically and in the console - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_home-directory-console.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for the suggestion, just changed my answer to include it. Not sure why I forgot it in the first place, when I made one like it just a few weeks ago :)